# Blank space below header on Wordpress (Avada)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a blank space below the header on one of my pages.

Below the header and above the "SERVICIOS 24 HORAS"

I don't find the CSS class of this.

> ```
> I'm using Avada theme.
> I'm using Visual Composer
> I'm using Directories Pro plugin for this page.
> ```

Someone can help me to remove this blank space?

Thanks!

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: Your issue isn't css, it's html. You have <p></p> tags when there shouldn't be, since you didn't post code you'll need to find them.

Comment: Code from which file?

Answer (score 0):

do you refer to the grey line above the "Servicios" slider? Or is the problem already fixed?

if you refer to the grey line, stick this somewhere in your custom css:

```
.avada-skin-rev {
    border-top: none!important;
}
```

[image]